# responsive website not resizing immediatelyin iframe

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, iframe

I do have the following iframe

HTML:

```
strResult += "<iframe class=\"divGrafico\" style='width:820px; height:400px' + id='" + split[1] + "' src=\"'+about:blank+'\"></iframe><br>";
$("#tblResultEstViewCliente").append(strResult);
```

and here I am adding the content

JavaScript:

```
 var doc = document.getElementById(split[1]).contentWindow.document;
 doc.open();
 doc.write(grafico);
 doc.close();
```

This iframe is in a dialog

When loading the dialog for the first time the iframe content is smaller than the iframe size, after reopening size is correct.

The content comes in an ajax request.
And is loaded every time the dialog is opened.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/danif88/165mj5h4/
I don't why in jsfiddle.net it shows ok... I am using the same version of jquery 1.7.2

Comment: Could be because is inside a dialog?